# Mailjet v3.1 mail sending failed with error code

Tags: node.js, email, mailjet

After i sign up to mailJet with my company email, i got the APIKey and secretKey.
But i still got this error message when i tried to send email.

```
{"Messages":[
    {"Errors":[
        {
            "ErrorIdentifier":"3ae7f07f-64df-4d6c-ae2e-e14b3d433a72",
            "ErrorCode":"send-0008",
            "StatusCode":403,
            "ErrorMessage":"myemail@companyName.com" is not an authorized sender email address for your account.",
            "ErrorRelatedTo":["From"]}
    ],"Status":"error"}
]
```

I have been checking online to find a way to solve this, any answer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your email isn't authorized probably because, it is not registered.

You have to go there :
[Account > Sender Adress](https://app.mailjet.com/account/sender)

Then, use [+ Add a sender address](https://app.mailjet.com/account/sender/add) button at the bottom of the page.

Once added, your email is listed with the status "Pending". Confirm your registration by activating the link in the mail send into your email box.

Answer (score 0):

The error message that you have received is actually self explanatory

> "myemail@companyName.com" is not an authorized sender email address for your account.

You should go through the process of validating the sender email address as described here : https://www.mailjet.com/support/am-i-limited-to-one-email-sending-address,96.htm or if you are using the API, then more information could be found from the API Guide at https://dev.mailjet.com/guides/#prerequisites

Once the sender has been validated, then you would be good to go.